# Hive - Incremental update materialized view

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql, materialized-views

Suppose I have a transactional table t1 as

```
1,abc,4.5
2,xyz,3.7
```

And I create a materialized view on it :

```
> create materialized view t1_mv as select * from t1;
```

Then I update the table :

```
> insert into t1 values (3,"lmn",4.7)
```

Now when I want to update the view I have to execute following query :

```
> ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW t1_mv REBUILD;
```

In above query rebuild operation triggers full scan on t1 table and rewrites materialized view.

As per Hive documentation : "*Hive supports incremental view maintenance, i.e., only refresh data that was affected by the changes in the original source tables. Incremental view maintenance will decrease the rebuild step execution time. In addition, it will preserve LLAP cache for existing data in the materialized view.*" [link to documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Materialized+views)

However the exact process is not mentioned about incremental update on materialized views,

My Questions are :

1. How to incrementally update materialized view ?
2. What is the role of LLAP cache in the process of incremental update ?

Comment: Don't the next two paragraphs in the doc that you linked answer your question?

Comment: Theoretically yes, however very less information is given to implement it.

Comment: "By default, **Hive will attempt to rebuild a materialized view incrementally, falling back to full rebuild if it is not possible.** Current implementation only supports incremental rebuild when there were INSERT operations over the source tables, while UPDATE and DELETE operations will force a full rebuild of the materialized view." Not sure whats there to implement.

Comment: Ohh, I thought I have to write different query for incrementally updating the view, are there any conditions which need to meet in order to incrementally update the materialized view ?